# Visual Studio namespace errors after deleting userControls

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, build-error

Really Visual Studio can be so annoying sometimes...

I did nothing else than deleting 3 UserControls in a folder. Since that time I get a error message I do not get rid of. Whatever I do I can not build successfully my project.

I did not touch the SchoolAdministrationUC.xaml file , but I deleted 3 other UserControls also located in the path: TBM\View\SchoolclassAdministration\

Error message from VS:

Error 1 The type or namespacename "SchoolclassAdministration" is in namespace "TBM.View" not available. (missing assembly reference?) E:\TBM\obj\x86\Debug\View\SchoolclassAdministration\SchoolAdministrationUC.g.cs 33 16 TBM

How do I get rid of error ?

Comment: Did you delete the CS file for your SchoolAdministrationUC.xaml file?  Probably named SchoolAdministrationUC.xaml.cs.

Comment: No I did NOT delete the SchoolAdministrationUC.xaml.cs file. Its still existing and I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fact that it shows the obj folder as where the error is, have you tried a clean build?  Or a complete rebuild?

Sounds like there is an object out there looking for a non-existent namespace.

Build -> Rebuild Solution

Comment: I did a clean solution, rebuild, build whatever... nothing helps :/

Comment: This thread: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/5436/16906.aspx seems to say that you can delete the schooladministrationuc.g.cs file because it's auto generated.  

Also, if you rollback your changes does it build again?

Comment: not in the obj folder but in the debug folder is the  schooladministrationuc.g.cs file located, I deleted it, rebuild and same problem...

too bad I did not put this yet under subversion so I can not rollback it FOO`K!!!

Comment: now I deleted the SchoolclassAdminUC.xaml and .cs file, obj and debug , properties folder, solution, project file etc.

Just getting some naked folders depending on nothing.

Then I did in VS 2010: File Menu: New Project from existing code, did a rebuild and I can not believe it now I get a even more stupid error message:


Error 1 the programm "e:\TBM\obj\x86\Debug\WindowsApplication.exe" contains no suitable static main-method as entry point. E:\TBM\CSC 

What the heck is file CSC ???

I dont neeed a static main method and I never had it before!

Comment: ah holy crap the buildaction of app.xaml was set to PAGE ??

I set it now to applicationdefinition to find the entry point...

time to check into subversion ;-)

Comment: eSeems the joy was too fast... after former copy of my xaml code and pasting back now in the newly created SchoolclassAdministrationUC.xaml file I get this error again:

Error 1 The type or namespacename "SchoolclassAdministration" is in namespace "TBM.View" not available. (missing assembly reference?) E:\TBM\obj\x86\Debug\View\SchoolclassAdministration\SchoolAdministrationUC.g.cs 33 16 TBM

Come on Microsoft is that all ??

Comment: When I delete the .cs file of the UserControl it rebuilds 100% but well I do ot follow MVVM pattern 100 % ;-)

Comment: After a long journey I created now a project from existing code and created the SchoolclassAdministrationView.xaml in the TBM\View and not in TBM\View\SchoolclassAdministration because then it shows no Namespace problem whyever...

hurray its up on subversion running XD

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up when you unwittingly create a new Windows application Project to add the existing code for a class library project in the same project folder. If the original class library project is not compatible with VS or you have any other issue then creating a new class class library is an option.